# How to use namespaces with xml.sax package

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, sax

I am trying to parse an XML file, including namespaces, with the Python `xml.sax` package, but it doesn't work. Below you will find an example from the internet, which I extended with the namespace "abc". Can someone show me a way to work with it?

This is the XML file:

```xml
<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
    <movie title="Enemy Behind">
        <type>War, Thriller</type>
        <format>DVD</format>
        <abc:year>2003</abc:year>
        <rating>PG</rating>
        <stars>10</stars>
        <description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>
    </movie>
    <movie title="Transformers">
        <type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>
        <format>DVD</format>
        <abc:year>1989</abc:year>
        <rating>R</rating>
        <stars>8</stars>
        <description>A schientific fiction</description>
    </movie>
    <movie title="Trigun">
        <type>Anime, Action</type>
        <format>DVD</format>
        <episodes>4</episodes>
        <rating>PG</rating>
        <stars>10</stars>
        <description>Vash the Stampede!</description>
    </movie>
    <movie title="Ishtar">
        <type>Comedy</type>
        <format>VHS</format>
        <rating>PG</rating>
        <stars>2</stars>
        <description>Viewable boredom</description>
    </movie>
</collection>
```

This is the Python code. Without the namespace, it works.

```
from xml.sax import make_parser, handler 

class Handler(handler.ContentHandler):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.CurrentData=""
        self.type = ""
        self.format = ""
        self.year = ""
        self.rating = ""
        self.stars = ""
        self.description = ""

    def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
        self.CurrentData = tag
        if tag == "movie":
            print("*****Movie*****")
            title = attributes["title"]
            print("Title:", title)

    def endElement(self, tag):
        if self.CurrentData == "type":
            print("Type:", self.type)
        elif self.CurrentData == "format":
            print("Format:", self.format)
        elif self.CurrentData == "year":
            print("Year:", self.year)
        elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
            print("Rating:", self.rating)
        elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
            print("Stars:", self.stars)
        elif self.CurrentData == "description":
            print("Description:", self.description)
        self.CurrentData = ""

    def characters(self, content):
        if self.CurrentData == "type":
            self.type = content
        elif self.CurrentData == "format":
            self.format = content
        elif self.CurrentData == "year":
            self.year = content
        elif self.CurrentData == "rating":
            self.rating = content
        elif self.CurrentData == "stars":
            self.stars = content
        elif self.CurrentData == "description":
            self.description = content

parser = make_parser()
p = Handler()
parser.setContentHandler(p)
parser.parse("sax03.xml")
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?